# server failover with Quarkus Reactive MySQL Clients / io.vertx.mysqlclient

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x, quarkus

Does `io.vertx.mysqlclient` support server failover [as it can be set up with MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-config-failover.html)?

My application is based on quarkus using `io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool` which in turn is based on `io.vertx.mysqlclient`. If there is support for server failover in that stack, how can it be set up? I did not find any hints in the documentation and code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it doesn't support failover.

You could create two clients and then use Munity failover methods to get the same effect:

```
MySQLPool client1 = ...
MySQLPool client2 = ...

private Uni<List<Data>> query(MySQLPool client) {
  // Use client param to send queries to the database
}

Uni<List<Data>> results = query(client1)
    .onFailure().recoverWithUni(() -> query(client2));
```